# Error: invalid input syntax for type numeric: "" (postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to alter the column data type in my postgresql table. The column name is `_2010_10`, type is text, and the value is 18.74 (in text format). I'm trying to change the text type to numeric. This is my input/output:

```
ALTER table cadata.pricetorentratio 
ALTER column _2010_10 type numeric USING (trim(_2010_10)::numeric);
```

> ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""

Not sure why I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `NULLIF` to handle blank string `''`:

```
ALTER table pricetorentratio 
ALTER column _2010_10 type numeric USING (NULLIF(trim(_2010_10),'')::numeric);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=23ce440f5243846a172ddfac9a18ca9e)**

---

```
SELECT ''::numeric
-- invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ALTER TABLE `pricetorentratio` CHANGE `_2010_10` `_2010_10` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```